# EMR-Spark is slow writing a DataFrame with an Array of Strings to S3

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to write a dataframe to S3 from EMR-Spark and I'm seeing some really slow write times where the writing comes to dominate the total runtime (~80%) of the script.  For what it's worth, I've tried both `.csv` and `.parquet` formats, it doesn't seem make a difference.

My data can be formatted in two ways, here's the preferred format:

**ID : StringType | ArrayOfIDs : ArrayType**

(The number of unique IDs in the first column numbers in the low millions. `ArrayOfIDs` contains GUID formatted strings, and can contain anywhere from ~100 - 100,000 elements)

Writing the first form to S3 is incredibly slow.  For what it's worth, I've tried setting the `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version` to `2` as described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20107 to no real effect.

However my data can also be formatted as an adjacency list, like this:

**ID1 : StringType | ID2 : StringType**

This appears to be much faster for writing to S3, but I am at a loss for why.  Here are my specific questions:

- Ultimately I'm trying to get my data into an Aurora RDS Postgres cluster (I was told firmly by those before me that the Spark JDBC connector is too slow for the job, which is why I'm currently trying to dump the data in S3 before loading it into Postgres with a `COPY` command).  I'm not married to using S3 as an intermediate store if there are better alternatives for getting these data frames into RDS Postgres.
- I don't know why the first schema with the Array of Strings is so much slower on write.  The total data written is actually far less than the second schema on account of eliminating ID duplication from the first column.  Would also be nice to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I still don't know why writing arrays directly from Spark is so much slower than the adjacency list format.  But best practice seems to dictate that I avoid writing to S3 directly from Spark.

Here's what i'm doing now:

- Write the data to HDFS (anecdotally, the write speed of the adjacency list vs the array now falls in line with my expectations).
- From HDFS, use EMR's s3-dist-cp utility to wholesale write the data to S3 (this also seems reasonably performant with array typed data).
- Bring the data into Aurora Postgres with the  `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3` extension.